# Реализация сохранения

Tags: c#, wpf, структуры

Скажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать сохранение в моей программе? У меня на сохранение пойдут все элементы из `canvas` (на картинке он есть) сохраняя дочерние объекты и их все свойства (`tag`, `name`, события если есть, `margin` и т.д.), а помимо графических элементов мне нужно ещё сохранить list (который тоже есть), который состоит из классов, в пример я привёл один класс и связки (красные стрелочки) которые обязательно будут. Я хотел всё сохранять в xml, но я не знаю правильно ли так делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться сохранять структуру UI. У вас должен быть [вью-]модельный, осмысленный объект, отображением которого и является ваш UI, его-то и нужно сохранять. UI должно строиться по этому объекту.

Comment: @VladD Подождите, можете чуть-чуть поподробнее про "[вью-]модельный, осмысленный объект", я просто все контролы добавляю при помощи canvas.Children.Add, а внутри добавленных контролов аналогично добавляю другие контролы.

Comment: @VladD Ну ладно, хорошо, а как тогда потом вью-модель сохранять?

Comment: Ну, придётся делать не так. Например, у вас должен быть список VM-объектов, и по нему автоматически строиться UI (через `ItemsControl` какой-нибудь). Строить UI вручную означает ограничивать WPF до WinForms.

Comment: А для модельных или VM-объектов, которые нужно сохранять, реализуйте XML-сериализацию (или JSON-сериализацию, так сейчас вроде бы моднее).

Comment: "VM-объекты", "JSON-сериализация", "ViewModel" мне ещё учиться и учиться, а точнее отучиваться от старого winforms )

Comment: Ничего сложного нет. Но вам стоит вкурить в MVVM, с ним вы поймёте мощь WPF. Честно. (VM и есть ViewModel.) А JSON-сериализация — это превращение объектов в JSON, сохранение в виде строки (и обычно запись в файл).

Comment: Идея простая и старая как мир: разделение контента и представления. Контент вы сохраняете, представление (UI) строится для контента автоматом.

Comment: @VladD Ну это понятно, чем больше знаешь тем легче работать, но вот вся сложность что у меня программа на 80% состоит из графических элементов и сложных графических структур как на картинке, а в интернете в основном уроки по mvvm делаются с текстовыми данными или числовыми.

Comment: Ну да, но эти сложные графические структуры ведь всё равно описывают какой-то объект. Вот этот объект и есть ваша VM или модель. И к нему можно привязываться. (И не смотрите видеоуроки, они ужасны! У нас тут есть куча вопросов по основам MVVM, лучше почитайте их.)

Comment: @VladD а вот что мне сделать с теми объектами которые перемещаются, мне хранить их координаты нужно будет на стороне контента или представления?

Comment: Окей, вопрос в том, **что** означает их положение? Если это план дома, например, и вы двигаете мебель, то на стороне модели у вас положение шкафа в сантиметрах, а на стороне представления — в пикселях. Коэффициент пересчёта зависит от текущего zoom-фактора.

Comment: @VladD ладно, у меня программа в общем состоит из модулей (grid'ов) которые соединяются между собой конекторами и мне вот нужно сохранить всё, но я вот начал с модулей и как я вас понял координаты должны храниться в каком нибудь условном классе module.x и module.y на стороне модели.

Comment: Ага, например, так. `Module` — это уже хорошее начало. Возможно, имеет смысл добавить больше семантики, то есть, сделать название более конкретным. Шкаф? Машина? Микросхема? Сарай? Взвод? Дачный участок?